# Setting ReLU inplace to 'False'

Tags: python, deep-learning, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model, relu

Below I have written code which accepts a pretrained model as argument (vgg, resnet, densenet etc) and returns the model with ReLU state as 'False'. It is written after testing many different specific architectures.

I would like to re-write it in a more compact way as this does not seem optimal to me. However, I am not a developer and do not have much coding experience. Could you please assist with this?

```
def ReLU_inplace_to_False (model):
    
    for module in model._modules.values():
        if isinstance(module, nn.ReLU):
            module.inplace = False
        try:
            for layer in module:
                if isinstance(layer, nn.ReLU):
                    layer.inplace = False
                try:
                    for sublayer in layer._modules.values():
                        if isinstance(sublayer, nn.ReLU):
                            sublayer.inplace = False
                        try:
                            for subsublayer in sublayer._modules.values():
                                if isinstance(subsublayer, nn.ReLU):
                                    subsublayer.inplace = False
                                try:
                                    for subsubsublayer in subsublayer._modules.values():
                                        if isinstance(subsubsublayer, nn.ReLU):
                                            subsubsublayer.inplace = False
                                except:
                                    pass
                        except:
                            pass
                except:
                    pass
        except:
            pass
    
    return model
```

Comment: Why are the try/except clauses there?  Those will hide everything including spelling errors.

Comment: Because if a module has only one layer it raises an error.. For instance if we take a VGG16, the following error comes up : "TypeError: 'AdaptiveAvgPool2d' object is not iterable"

Comment: You should be able to check that and skip the iteration.

Comment: Yes I tried that.. but couldn't find a condition that works.. and as a result i used the try/except statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This calls for a recursive solution.

```
def ReLU_inplace_to_False(module):
    for layer in module._modules.values():
        if isinstance(layer, nn.ReLU):
            layer.inplace = False
        ReLU_inplace_to_False(layer)
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance :) .. I think the last line "ReLU_inplace_to_False(layer)" should be moved one tab backwards.. Is this correct ? I tried the code with a Resnet101 and the ReLU inplace becomes "False" when the recursive call takes place outside of the if statement..

Comment: You're right, I got fooled by the `try`, making it look like that was at the same level as the `if` block.